# Find the output of the code snippet and explain

Tags: java

```
{
  long a = 78345, s1 = 0, s2 = 0, r;
  while(a>0)
  {
    r=a % 10
    if (r % 4 == 0)
      s1 += r;
    else
      s2 += r;
    a /= 10;
  }

  System.out.println("S1= "+ s1 );
  System.out.println("S2= "+ s2 );

}
```

find the answer for s1 and s2.
explain the steps and process.

PLEASE go easy on me, learning java yet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about compiling a program to determine the result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where we don't go easy.

Comment: @christopher i am learning java out of a book, i dont have any professor or a teacher.

Comment: @devnull this question is from the text book and it doesnt even answer about it.

Comment: @Javalearner If you copied the code verbatim, then throw away the book.  The snippet even contains a syntax error.  (Hint: a missing semicolon.)

Comment: @Javalearner Moreover, if you acquire a minimal understand of operators (division, modulo, ...) then you'd be able to answer the question.  Read a basic tutorial.  Search for "Java Nuts and Bolts" and start reading that.

Comment: @ devnull well its the only reference book prescribed and i got exam of it weighing 25 marks, in 3 days. after that i will gladly throw away the book...

Comment: for a Start `C /= A is equivalent to C = C / A` similar for `C +=A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `r=a % 10` statement gets the units digit of a which at first is `5`.

then `if (r % 4 == 0)` checks if the number is evenly divisible by four and if it is, then the number is added to `s1` and the result is stored in `s1`, if not, the number is added to `s2` and the result is stored in `s2`.

so at the end, `s1 = 8 + 4 = 12` and `s2 = 7 + 3 + 5 = 15`

Comment: what happens to 5 which has been taken earlier?

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot to explain that. The `a /= 10;` line does an integer division(divide the number and throw away the remainder) of a for every iteration of the loop.`a /= 10` is equivalent to `a = a/10;`. So, first `a = 78345` and `a /= 10` means `78345/10 = 7834`. Then, `7834/10 = 783` and so on..